# Specifying a named SQL Server instance for nhibernate

Tags: database, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, instance, sessionfactory

I've been making a first attempt to use fluent nHibernate on an ASP.NET MVC 3 application. Because I have multiple instances of SQL Server Express, I've been trying to specify a named instance along with the server while creating a session factory with the Fluently.Configure() method. My connection string for the database is of the format:

```
Server=myServerName\theInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

This causes an nHibernate exception reading:

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification
>   starting at index 19

where the index given corresponds to the slash before the instance name. This connection string works fine with Entity Framework 4. So how am I to specify the named instance I want to connect to in nHibernate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are doing that in code, you must escape the `\` either by doubling it (`\\`) or by using a verbatim string:

```
connectionString = @"Server=myServerName\theInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;..."
```

Otherwise, `\t` is interpreted as the tab character.

Comment: That was it. Clearly a case where the answer was staring me in the face while I was looking to hard to notice.